# Incorrect datetime value displayed using flask from MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, flask, mysql-connector

I have a database stores, which has a table called s_status with attributes: id, timestampInUTC. The timestampInUTC attribute consists of timestamps upto 6 fractions in datatype datetime(6). I loaded the data into the database from a csv file.

> This is the actual data: (in .csv file)
>
> `8,2001-02-18 20:00:33 UTC`

> code1: (MYSQL WORKBENCH)
>
> ```
> use stores;
> select timestampInUTC from s_status where id=8;
> ```
>
> its output:
>
> `'active', '2001-02-18 20:00:33'`

> code2: (FLASK)
>
> ```
> db = mysql.connector.connect(
>   host="localhost",
>   user="root")
> cursor = db.cursor()
> cursor.execute("USE stores")
> cursor.execute("SELECT timestampInUTC from s_status where id=8")
> data = []
> for i in cursor:
>   data.append(i)
> app = Flask(__name__)
> @app.route("/test_route")
> def test_route():
>   return {"8": data}
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5010, debug=True)
> ```
>
> its output:
>
> ```
> {  
>    "8": [
>     [
>       "active", 
>       "Fri, 18 Feb 2001 14:30:33 GMT"
>     ]
> }
> ```

I have also configured MySQL server time to '+00:00' (in the my.cnf file):

```
default-time-zone='+00:00'
```

I live in UTC +05:30 timezone.

I came across the following in the [documents](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html#:%7E:text=MySQL%20retrieves%20and%20displays%20DATE,%3Amm%3Ass%20%27%20format.)

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.(This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.) By default, the current time zone for each connection is the server's time.

If this is the case, since I am storing the timestamp in DATETIME there shouldn't be any time conversion. Even if there is.. since the server's time is set to '00:00' there shouldn't be an issue. I can't figure out why exactly flask displays what it displays. Can anyone explain me how it works?

Thank you for spending your valuable time on my question

Comment: You prove that this is Flask who adjusts the datetime value.